# parsing/converting task with characters and numbers within

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, numbers

It is necessary to repeat the character, as many times as the number behind it.

They are positive integer numbers.

```
case #1

input: "abc3leson11"

output: "abccclesonnnnnnnnnnn"
```

I already finish it in the following way:

```
    String a = "abbc2kd3ijkl40ggg2H5uu";
    String s = a + "*";
    String numS = "";
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            numS = numS + ch;
            cnt++;
        } else {
            cnt++;
            try {
                for (int j = 0; j < Integer.parseInt(numS); j++) {
                    System.out.print(s.charAt(i - cnt));
                }
                if (i != s.length() - 1 && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i + 1))) {
                    System.out.print(s.charAt(i)); 
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (i != s.length() - 1 && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i + 1))) {
                    System.out.print(s.charAt(i)); 
                }
            }
            cnt = 0;
            numS = "";
        }

    }
```

But I wonder is there some better solution with less and cleaner code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using java basic string `regx` should make it more terse as follows:

```
public class He1 {
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+(\\d+).*");  
    // match the number between or the last using regx;
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String s = "abc3leson11";
        System.out.println(parse(s));
        s = "abbc2kd3ijkl40ggg2H5uu";
        System.out.println(parse(s));
    }

    private static String parse(String s) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            int num = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
            char prev = s.charAt(s.indexOf(String.valueOf(num)) - 1); 
            // locate the char before the number;
            String repeated = new String(new char[num-1]).replace('\0', prev); 
            // since the prev is not deleted, we have to decrement the repeating number by 1;
            s = s.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(num), repeated);
            matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

And the output should be:

```
abccclesonnnnnnnnnnn
abbcckdddijkllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllggggHHHHHuu
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you take a look below? I'm using a library from `StringUtils` from **Apache Common Utils** to repeat character:

```
public class MicsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "abc3leson11";
        String output = input;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
          int number = Integer.valueOf(m.group());
          char repeatedChar = input.charAt(m.start()-1);
          output = output.replaceFirst(m.group(), StringUtils.repeat(repeatedChar, number));
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

In case you don't want to use `StringUtils`. You can use the below custom method to achieve the same effect:

```
    public static String repeat(char c, int times) {
        char[] chars = new char[times];
        Arrays.fill(chars,  c);
        return new String(chars);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String g(String a){
  String result = "";
  String[] array = a.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
  //System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array));
  for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    String part = array[i];
    result += part;
    if(++i == array.length){
      break;
    }
    char charToRepeat = part.charAt(part.length() - 1);
    result += repeat(charToRepeat+"", new Integer(array[i]) - 1);
  }
  return result;
}

// In Java 11 this could be removed and replaced with the builtin `str.repeat(amount)`
String repeat(String str, int amount){
  return new String(new char[amount]).replace("\0", str);
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##zVRLc9owEL7nV2x8yEhV4iFpewImkymdaQ@9lN6AgzDCyBjbI8lpmZTfTleWNAgok@ZWHfRY7ePbZ8Gf@V2xWO/3Wcm1hm9cVi9XAE07L2UG2nCDx3MtF7DBLzI2Slb5ZAZc5ZpaToDxVhuxSevWpA3@mrIiS5Lw@Tx7WC/ey2Jdfujlef7w5WPbJpT2LwnlrwjtrnDziBwOWHpAwAMW91RCt6WBISRJP6ZrJHFgkLw7plftZhxxIx7IKivfc4RlrYBYquxoeAxAp6WocrMiFN@MUXAI7MpWXOGGvDq19ydDpPe7U78E8gnJPDNCpVKPZC4NyVY01mGXh9UdDBX2j34RIWMH0g5EqcWJhhMeu4zanjAdeVg4Dwv08GtlRI4IG660wAexQNDb4tjbePnAs9hzuLMwaP9MYHdGsZGRcD2MgovS93BzA9fnEYtMMLin9C2g0I1X8Owg4waTSD7/ykRjZF2B@JuF/wrzafIPJXxSU6HUD1JuV8K0qvLmL3Rd/rau66aF4lvbe6luSoxCQh4Hw@l0RMkjHgv6270X7j2iyeUpUeDESlsjy/TJKtWpqZ0Z0hkJ8wXr2TXs0LbroPvz@XHtGsLusWONW@Qd30TOQnAOabAMgSqXhDEcBZ7f66WHTM6V4OvAHZLipwJXP@rvohHc2rNaQ367e1xC9ByF6gRJrIUlyS1U4mdoVxJ8iHX8e3K9hTAwjbrtxiHf1C028Uusxxr1sbdXC2ri@GY0RT0lzwRJpj3Eh3r8DN/t938A)

**Explanation:**

The split will split the letters and numbers:
`abbc2kd3ijkl40ggg2H5uu` would become `["abbc", "2", "kd", "3", "ijkl", "40", "ggg", "2", "H", "5", "uu"]`

We then loop over the parts and add any strings as is to the result.

We then increase `i` by 1 first and if we're done (after the `"uu"`) in the array above, it will break the loop.

If not the increase of `i` will put us at a number. So it will repeat the last character of the part `x` amount of times, where `x` is the number we found minus 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
String str = "abbc2kd3ijkl40ggg2H5uu";
    String[] part = str.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?=\\d)(?<=\\D)");
    String res = "";
    for(int i=0; i < part.length; i++){
        if(i%2 == 0){
            res = res + part[i];
        }else {
            res = res + StringUtils.repeat(part[i-1].charAt(part[i-1].length()-1),Integer.parseInt(part[i])-1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution :

```
public static String getCustomizedString(String input) {
    ArrayList<String > letters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split("(\\d)")));
    letters.removeAll(Arrays.asList(""));
    ArrayList<String > digits = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split("(\\D)")));
    digits.removeAll(Arrays.asList(""));

    for(int i=0; i< digits.size(); i++) {
        int iteration = Integer.valueOf(digits.get(i));
        String letter = letters.get(i);
        char c = letter.charAt(letter.length()-1);
        for (int j = 0; j<iteration -1 ; j++) {
            letters.set(i,letters.get(i).concat(String.valueOf(c)));
        }
    }
    String finalResult = "";
    for (String str : letters) {
        finalResult += str;
    }

    return finalResult;
}
```

The usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testString1 = "abbc2kd3ijkl40ggg2H5uu";
    String testString2 = "abc3leson11";
    System.out.println(getCustomizedString(testString1));
    System.out.println(getCustomizedString(testString2));
}
```

And the result:

```
abbcckdddijkllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllggggHHHHHuu
abccclesonnnnnnnnnnn
```